# React Native post request like a form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native

I am trying to achieve a similar thing in React Native any idea how can i do this

```
<form action="http://example.com/some-url-end-point" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="q" value="a">
</form>
```

Is there a possibility to do something similar in React Native. I can do this in a web application. But in react native `window.document` doesn't exist. So I can't submit a form dynamically or in any way.

Basically what happens is I send some data to a 3rd party payment gateway with POST method data. Any idea how I can achieve this in React Native?

**Edit:**
I need a solution that changes when submitted a web view opens up which changes the location of the browser, and sends data to that location in `post` method format

A similar question I found regarding this for Javascript implementation was this [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)
 I need to achieve something similar in react native.

Comment: would you put your final code to this post? 
I've got the same issue with this code snippet, I'm using Webview but  `document.forms[0].submit()` or any similar submission not work and not send me to the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since what you are trying to do is actually create a web form and redirect after that, why not create your form using HTML? You can do it using `WebView`. It's `source` prop accepts HTML directly or a remote source, and by doing so you can get the result you wish.

Comment: Oh i think this will work, I will look into this. Thank you

Comment: Any idea how I can submit the loaded form in source prop as html on web view load? As in as soon the web view loads with the html submit the form automatically?

Comment: As webview accepts javascript, best way to go at it would be to use javascript code there. You can either include it directly, or use ```injectJavaScript``` / ```injectedJavaScript```. First one is a function that will allow you to inject JS and execute immediately. Second is a prop that executes given JS when the view loads.

Comment: Hi @AdeelImran, did you managed to implement  HTML form POST behaviour in react native? I am finding way to do it as well.

Answer (score 5):

There is no equivalent in React Native to the html form.

All network requests are done with some networking library. React Native comes with fetch built in, but you can also use something like Axios, or even the XMLHttpRequest object itself.

See the [Networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) section in the React Native docs.

There are some libraries for the form UI, but they usually just provide you with the values in the form elements, which you then have to send on your own.

Comment: So how can I mimic a behavior where I open a webview and a link opens up in which I have send some data in a `POST` format.

Comment: A webview is basically a browser window. Any web page you load will behave the same as it would in a normal browser, including forms. Then again, that's not what you asked about.

Comment: So how can I `post` data to a url. And open that url in a web view? That URL is not 'GET' method. It is of 'POST' method

Comment: A `POST` method is used to sent data to a server. Are you saying you want to display the result of that in a web view?

Comment: No, I need to open a URL of type 'POST' and send some data to that URL. You generally do that with `<form action="POST_URL" method="post" />` in web apps, but how can you do that in react native.

Comment: As I said in the answer, use `fetch`, it allows you to send `POST` requests.

Comment: @AdeelImran you have to do as Kraylog suggest use network library to send the post, the url you are going to be sending will have to responses with a static html content, you have to set a state with that responses in your state tree in you react native app, that state is going to be use by the webView in the source props https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#source

Comment: @Angel Have a look at user (h-tugkan-kibar) answer. That is what I was looking for.